# NFC handover to Bluetooth or WiFi for data transfer

Tags: bluetooth, nfc, file-transfer, touchscreen, android-bluetooth

I'm currently working on a project for an interactive visitor centre in Laguna Beach, CA.

There are many touchscreen devices around the space, which we are developing some cool software for, however one of the client requests is to allow visitors to transfer image, pdf and video files from an interactive coffee table touchscreen onto their phone.

The client has seen this on YouTube/CES etc..  You know, where someone puts a phone on a the interactive surface and then magically swipes images onto the phone from the screen.

Of course, if the visitor had a custom app on their phone, and was already on the same WiFi this would not be so much of a problem.  I suspect this is what happens on these magic demos that we see.

In our situation, we don't want the visitor to download an app really, we just want the easiest solution and experience for the visitor.  We have a public WiFi available to us, and we can install an NFC device on the touchscreen and the touchscreen also has bluetooth.

My ideal scenario would be for the user to pop their NFC enabled phone on the table, the table recognises it, pairs with BT or WiFi and away we go!  I'm not sure how practical this is though having researched around.  Clearly thats not going to work on an iPhone.  I don't mind a couple of mechanisms i.e. one for Android/other NFC phones and one for iPhone.

Does anyone have any experience of this kind of thing and suggestions of how to handle it?!

[Here's a mock up of our 32" Coffee Table touchscreen just for some context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zz2T.jpg)

Thanks for reading through and having a think :-)

Comment: really like to know how your project is coming along. I am currently developing a simple nfc enable "vcard" app for event visitors, but i am interested it all event related apps.

Answer (score 1):

I know that there is standardized way to pair Bluetooth device using NFC tag. I think this is the best solution for you. The authority that is standardizing this format is called NFC Forum. You can find more info about the topic in this document: [Bluetooth Secure Simple Pairing Using NFC](http://members.nfc-forum.org/resources/AppDocs/NFCForum_AD_BTSSP_1_0.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Kamen - I had seen that document actually, but it scared me a little!  I was hoping to find someone who had implemented a solution already and perhaps had some code/SDK etc...